# Where Konqueror keeps its bookmarks?

Tags: linux, kde, konqueror

KDE/Konqueror, lots of bookmarks (mostly SSH/fish:// bookmarks, so those are actually useful). I have a backup script, but do not know how I can extract Konqueror bookmarks for backing them up?

Comment: I'm not certain (hence why this isn't an answer) but you might find some useful thing in ~/.local/{share,} and ~/.config/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/home/username/.kde/share/apps/konqueror/bookmarks.xml
```

Comment: This is no longer correct - as of Konqueror v20.8. Any idea where it is now?